# AngularJS push to array parse in view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a controller where I declare the model like this:

```
$scope.Model =[];
```

after I make a rest call and the result I push it to the model:

```
$scope.Model.push(results.data);
```

The data returned can be in different length and size:

```
Name
Email
Items
   Item 1
   Item 2
   Item n
Roles
   Role 1
   Role 2
   Role n
```

What is the best practice of handling this with arrays in AngularJS and using ng-repeat in view in order to show the data?

Should I declare my array like this:

```
$scope.Model =[];
```

and push the results:

```
$scope.Model.push(results.data);
```

or like this:

```
$scope.Model =[{
   Name: '',
   Email: '',
   Items: [{
       Id: '',
       Name: '',
       Price: ''
   }],
   Roles: [{
       Id: '',
       Name: ''
   }], 
}];
```

and asign the results:

```
$scope.Model = results.data;
```

Comment: I just discovered `angular.copy(results.data, $scope.Model)`! Oau! I don't need to declare all that properties! Really?

Answer (score 0):

It is based on your response and scenarios. but ng-repeat expects `Array` or `Array list`.

**1) Array**

***Example 1 (plain array response)***

```
$scope.names= ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"];

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names">
      {{ x }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

***Example 2 (Object response that has array)***

```
$scope.names= {
"fruits": ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
};

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names.fruits">
      {{ x }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**2) Array List**

***Example 1 (plain array list response)***

```
$scope.names = [{
"id": "1",
"name": "Asik"
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John"
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Smith"
}];

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names">
         id:{{ x.id }}, name:{{ x.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

***Example 2 (Object response that has array list)***

```
$scope.names = {
"success": "true",
"items": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Asik"
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John"
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Smith"
}]
};

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names.items">
         id:{{ x.id }}, name:{{ x.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Basically, service/ajax response comes as `Array` or `Array list`. So you don't need to do the following steps.

```
$scope.Model =[];
$scope.Model.push(results.data);
```

But the above case comes in some situation (for eg: merging 2 service/ajax responses )

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following:

```
angular.copy(results.data, $scope.Model)
```

This will actually copy the results from the rest servicve into my model without having to declare each property of the model.